# Game center not authenticating in simulator for iPhone 4 inch

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, game-center

I implemented Center and it works fine doing authentication, reporting score to leaderboard and displaying score to player. On iPhone Retina (3.5 inch) simulator and iPhone Retina (4.0 inch) simulator in Xcode  authentication screen pups up suggesting player to sigh in to game center, but on iPhone Retina(4-inch - 64-bit) simulator authentication screen doesn't appear at all. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simulator sometimes authentication view not displayed.

So goto **Settings->General->Reset->Reset Location and Warnings**.

Also Reset Content and Settings in finder menu.

Here is Game Center authentication code:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalUser
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0"))
    {
        app.isgameCenterViewDisplayed = true;
        // ios 5.x and below
        [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
         {
             [self checkLocalPlayer];
         }];
    }
    else
    {

        // ios 6.0 and above
        [localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error)
                                             {
                                                 if (!error && viewcontroller)
                                                 {
                                                     [App.navController
                                                      presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
                                                 }
                                                 else
                                                 {
                                                     [self checkLocalPlayer];
                                                 }
                                             })];
    }
}
```

I got authentication in iPhone Retina(4inch 64bit) simulator also :)
[image]

Comment: THANKS FOR REPLY IN ADVANCE I WILL TRY THIS NOW AND TELL YOU IF EVERYTHING WENT GOOD!

Comment: OH! GURURAJ.T YOU ARE GENIUS!! THANK YOU SO MUCH, NOW I CAN FINALY SUBMIT AN UPTADE OF MY APP!!! Now I can go back to lowercase haha. I stock with this problem for two days and didnt want to look stupid when I have game center and it doesnt work in my app. Thanks a lot I greatly apreciate your help and I marked your reply as answered so everybody why has this problem know this is solution to the problem. Is there way I could give you + rating in this website?